Ferrites between grounds - specific to automotive design?
I have inherited an automotive design that needs some updating and I am questioning the use of ferrites to split the ground plane. The board uses +12V and 0V, and the ferrites split this ground plane between the vehicle's chassis ground 0V(E).
I have seen similar questions listing the disadvantages, but I wondered if there might be a reason specific to automotive, as I lack experience in this industry. There is an ADC and SMPS on the board but nothing critical or elaborate. I might use a pi filter on the positive input stage, but not on the return path.


What matters is not so much what the module is doing, but what else it's connected to, how it's wired. EMC is a subject of holistic scope; you need to look much more broadly than this.

I believe the answer is as simple as ADCs need a "quiet" ground and automobiles have a notoriously noisy ground. But I've also seen ferrites bridging the digital and analog ground domains on the same PCB, so it's not exactly an auto-only design feature.
Take a look as well at this cutsheet for some ideas of what to expect on the 12V bus. I'd take it with a grain of salt - unsurprisingly the company selling circuit protection devices is going to play up the risks - but it's a good starting point.
